# Filtering data in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot for my application with spring repository interfaces (with abstract methods and query annotations) for retrieve data. For the application purposes, we use the same schema in a db for multiple tenants. While retrieving data from the database I need to append the tenant id in criteria. I can’t do this manually in all queries as its a pain in the longer run.

Example repository:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
     // Methods come here
}
```

I need to filter data that are returned by the default findOne, findAll, etc methods as well.

PS: I came to know about Hibernate filters, but not sure how to configure hibernate filters in spring as hibernate session in completely abstracted in spring.

Comment: You can use hibernate filters for that pretty easy (although it requires adding a `@Filter` to all your entities to which it applies). The `EntityManager` can be unwrapped to a `Session` on which you can active the filter and set the tenant id. You could use AOP to enable the filters on each service call for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @M.Deinum. I am a newbie to Spring. Could you help me with an example link or something, so that I can check the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Multitenancy with Spring Data Jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135582/how-to-enable-multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the property you want to find after findBy, example:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

    List<Object> findById(String id);
}
```

Then just call it from your service or controller and pass the ID;

```
final MyRepository myRepository;

myRepository.findById('1556');
```

Depending the type of your id, do the right conversions