# How to enable Multitenancy with Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

**Background :** I am building a Multitenant SaaS app and have chosen single database, shared schema as the Multitenancy approach. Every table has a discriminator column "tenantId" to isolate the tenant data. I am using spring boot as the application framework and leveraging spring data jpa for the data layer with Hibernate as the JPA provider. I really like the way spring data helps in eliminating boilerplate code and have currently coded the respositories like below,

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{

}
```

and services like below,

```
public class UserService{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    public User getUser(){
        User user = userRepo.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:** When i want to get user, i want to get the user for a particular org. I am wondering how do i add the tenant criteria, i do not want to write custom repository implementations as that will introduce boilerplate code.

**Solutions Attempted:**

i) Hibernate Interceptor - onPrepareStatememt : This is not useful as the sql is a string and i do not want to do string manipulation.

ii)Enabling Hibernate Filters with Spring AOP: Annotated entity with @Filter and tried setting the filter in session. This does not work as the aspect is never invoked.

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.OpenSession(..))", returning = "session")
public void forceFilter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object session) {

    Session hibernateSession = (Session) session;
    session.enableFilter("tenantFilter")
}
```

The hibernate filters sounds like a promising approach but i have kind of hit the wall trying to put in a working solution. I would like to know if there is an alternate approach to enable the hibernate filter in the session that Spring data uses internally to query the data.

Comment: Obvouisly the AOP will not work as the point cut will simply never match... The `EntityManagerFactory` is used to get an `EntityManager` NOT a `Session` and it is `createEntityManager`. The returned `EntityManager` can be `unwrap` ed to a `Session` to enable the filter. However after enabling it you will also have to set the correct `tenantId` as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

I have blogged about [Multi-tenant applications using Spring Boot, JPA, Hibernate and Postgres](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/01/17/Multitenant-applications-using-Spring-Boot-JPA-Hibernate-and-Postgres.html) and even though I took the DB per tenant approach, the `DISCRIMINATOR` (One or multiple table columns used to specify different tenants) approach you are using most-likely requires less configuration.

Take a look at the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` implementation (**TenantDvdRentalIdentifierResolverImpl.java**), the **DvdRentalMultiTenantInterceptor.java**  `Spring MVC` interceptor and **DvdRentalTenantContext.java** that uses the `ThreadLocal` to store / pass the tenantId.

Comment: Looks like hibernate has not implemented the DISCRIMINIATOR based multitenancy strategy yet, the issue (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6054) is still open.

Comment: I believe Hibernate 5 does