# How to avoid a lot of duplicate code for JPA Repositories?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

In my jHipster project there are many tables and for each of them a repository interface is created. I need to implement multi-tenancy, 
so I'm going to add several methods, one of the parameters of which is departmentId like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Client> {

    @Query( value = "select * from client c  where department_id in (select id  from department where path like %?1%)" ,nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Client> findAllBydepartmentId(@Param("departmentId") String departmentId, Pageable pageable) ;

    @Query( value = "select * from client c  where client_id = ?2 and department_id in (select id  from department where path like %?1%)" ,nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Client> findAllBydepartmentId(@Param("departmentId") String departmentId, @Param("clientId"), Pageable pageable);

    @Query( value = "delete  from client c  where client_id = ?2 and department_id in (select id  from department where path like %?1%)" ,nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Client> findAllBydepartmentId(@Param("departmentId") String departmentId, @Param("clientId"), Pageable pageable);
```

I have to do that for each entity, so how to  avoid writing a lot of duplicate code?

Comment: I don't see how the code will be duplicate, it will only be very similar. The problem description is very unclear. What would the code be for another entity, so a comparison can be made? And do realize your example snippet has a find method which executes a delete query.

Comment: Yes, You 're right - not duplicate, but very similar. For other entity it will:
 @Query( value = "select * from invoice i  where department_id in (select id  from department where path like %?1%)" ,nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Invoice> findAllBydepartmentId(@Param("departmentId") String departmentId, Pageable pageable) ;

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135582/how-to-enable-multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa) will help?